# Want to use my google sheet custom search menu for multiple tab sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been trying to make a custom menu for searching data from my another tab Sheet but I want to make that for multiple sheets please can anyone help me so that I can fix this problem I am sharing my code here I tried by using sheet array and looping around but then multiple times that search pop-up coming.

```
function onOpen() {

  let ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  let menu= ui.createMenu('menu')
  menu.addItem('Search','showInputBox');
  menu.addItem('Clear','ClearCells');

  menu.addToUi();
 
  
}

function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('A2:O500').clearContent();
   
}


function showInputBox() {

    let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    let input = ui.prompt("Enter the searching item", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
        let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        let ws = ss.getSheetByName('APAC');

        let data = ws.getRange("A2:O47").getValues();
        let userText = input.getResponseText();
        let newData = data.filter(r => {
            return r.some(cell => String(cell ? cell : "").trim() === userText);
        });
        let newWs = ss.getSheets()[0];
        

         newWs.getRange(2,1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);



    }
    else if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
        //Do something
    }
    else if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

I tried this code but need little help

```
var sheetListArray = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"] 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
for( var i = 1 ; i <= sheetListArray.length ; i++) 
showInputBox(sheetListArray[i]); }
```

Comment: What''s it doing and how is it different to what you want?

Comment: This will make a custom menu in which pop up will come for searching and if any cell string match it will print the whole row into my searching tab sheet but this is only working in APAC sheet i want to use this searching for multiple tab sheets...

Answer (score 0):

```
function showInputBox() {
    let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    let input = ui.prompt("Enter the searching item", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
        let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        let ws = ss.getSheetByName('APAC');
        let data = ws.getRange("A2:O47").getValues();
        let tf = ws.createTextFinder(input.getResponseText()).findAll();
        let html = '';
        tf.forEach(f => {
          html += `row: ${f.getRow()} col: ${f.getColumn()}`
        });
        ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Results')
    } else {
      us.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('No results found'));
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to use this search function in multiple sheets like
Let sheets =["APAC","EMEA"] like this i want to use this operation in multiple sheets this one is only working in single sheet

Comment: You can use textFinder in multiple sheets

Comment: yes but i tried `let sheetListArray = ["APAC", "EMEA"] 
for( let i = 0 ; i <=sheetListArray.length ; i++) 
showInputBox(sheetListArray[i])` putting this so it will loop but it is no working for second sheet